# Toggle function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a toggle that toggles between two classes when clicked on the object with function "openclose(j)". I tried making the script only removeClass("arrow-down"), which works fine, but it wont addClass("arrow-up"). This is really annoying to deal with :)

```
    function openclose(j){
        if(jQuery('#div_'+j).hasClass("arrow-down")) {
            jQuery('#div_'+j).removeClass("arrow-down").addClass("arrow-up");
        }
        if (jQuery('#div_'+j).hasClass("arrow-up")) {
            jQuery('#div_'+j).removeClass("arrow-up").addClass("arrow-down");
        }

        jQuery('#collaps_'+j).toggle(
            function () {

            }
        );
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated,

Regards,
Mathias

Comment: As a side note, you should look into using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) :)

Answer (score 6):

You could use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) which does what you require:

```
function openclose(j){
    jQuery('#div_'+j).toggleClass("arrow-down").toggleClass("arrow-up");
}
```

Comment: Great! this helps out perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

Use an **else** if statement...

```
function openclose(j){
    if(jQuery('#div_'+j).hasClass("arrow-down")) {
        jQuery('#div_'+j).removeClass("arrow-down").addClass("arrow-up");
    }
    else if (jQuery('#div_'+j).hasClass("arrow-up")) {
        jQuery('#div_'+j).removeClass("arrow-up").addClass("arrow-down");
    }

    jQuery('#collaps_'+j).toggle(
        function () {

        }
    );
}
```

The problem is that you are removing the "arrow-up" class immediate after you add it!

Alternatively you could consider using the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) JQuery function.

Comment: jQuery has a `toggleClass()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `.toggleClass()` ?

```
jQuery('#div_'+j).toggleClass("arrow-down").toggleClass("arrow-up");
```